# how to get the 'id' of form id in jquery

Tags: jquery, django, django-views

I am not able to pass the `form id` to the views.py page.
jQuery does not passes the 'id' to the views page. Kindly tell me what I am doing wrong.

Here is my jQuery.

```
$(function(){
        $('.chatroom').submit(function () {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",

                url: "/dashboard",
                data : {
                            'chatroom_id' : $(this).attr('id')
                        },

                    });

            });
```

Here is my template

```
{% for key, values in chat_data.items %}
        <div class="container-fluid" alt = {{key}}>
            <div class="row-fluid">
               <div class="span2">
                 {{values.from}} <br/> {{values.init_query}}
                </div>

            <div class="span10 well">

                {% for k in values.chat %}

                        <label> Text : {{k.text}} </label> 
                        <label> {{k.date_time}} </label>

                {% endfor %}        

            <form action = "#" method = "POST" id = {{key}} class="chatroom">
               {% csrf_token %}
                   {{ form.as_p }}

                <input type="submit" value = "Sent" class="btn btn-primary"> 
            </form>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Views.py

```
if request.is_ajax():
    if request.method == "POST":
        chatroom_id = request.POST['chatroom_id']
else:
    chatroom_id =''

print chatroom_id
```

When I remove `if request.is_ajax()` condition , then it shows the error saying `"Key 'chatroom_id' not found in <QueryDict: {u'reply': [u''], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'yIJct9O7WfyPnWmDosW9N5TEklRwoIHP']}>"`

Comment: you should remove the last `,` after the `data` closing bracket

Comment: Did you checked the page source? are you getting the `{{key}}` value?

Comment: @KhawerZeshan- Yes key value is there in the page source. ANy suggestions please

Comment: Yes @KhawerZeshan- Key value does exist. and form id has it.

Comment: You need to prevent the default submit action `e.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 1):

You say you have to remove the `is_ajax()` method, which shows that actually you are not seeing the Ajax post at all, but the standard browser form submission. This is because you have not prevented the default submit action in your jQuery code.

It should be:

```
$('.chatroom').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is not the cause of your problem, but will cause a JS bug (syntax errors):

```
$(function(){
    $('.chatroom').submit(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/dashboard",
            data : {
                chatroom_id: $(this).attr('id')
            } // you had a dangling comma here
        });
    }); // you were missing a closing bracket and paren here
});
```

Comment: I noticed that typo error earlier, but still I am  not able to get the result out of it. Any suggestions please